# SICP Ex2.41: map and flatmap

Tags: scheme, filtering, sicp, map-function, flatmap

In SICP Exercise 2.41 the authors ask you to design a procedure that makes lists of three different numbers that are smaller than a certain number, and than "filter" the triplets whose sums are equal to another arbitrary number.

Here's my program:

```
(define (unique-pair-sum n s)
  (define (unique-triplet a) 
        (flatmap (lambda (i)
           (flatmap (lambda (j)
              (map (lambda (k) (list i j k))
                 (enumerate-interval 1 (- j 1))))
              (enumerate-interval 1 (- i 1))))
           (enumerate-interval 1 a)))
  (filter (lambda (x) (= (+ (car x) (cadr x) (caddr x)) s)) 
          (unique-triplet n)))
```

and here's the `flatmap` procedure as described in the book:

```
(define (flatmap proc seq) (accumulate append nil (map proc seq)))
```

and the result of an example:

```
(unique-pair-sum 6 9) ; ((4 3 2) (5 3 1) (6 2 1))
```

As you can see the there's nothing wrong with this code, however when I change the "`flatmap`" before `(lambda (j)...)` to simply "`map`", something weird happens:

```
(unique-triplet 6) ; (() () ((3 2 1)) () ((4 2 1)) ((4 3 1) (4 3 2)) () ((5 2 1)) ((5 3 1) (5 3 2)) ((5 4 1) (5 4 2) (5 4 3)) () ((6 2 1)) ((6 3 1) (6 3 2)) ((6 4 1) (6 4 2) (6 4 3)) ((6 5 1) (6 5 2) (6 5 3) (6 5 4)))
```

but the original code works just fine:

```
(unique-triplet 6) ; ((3 2 1) (4 2 1) (4 3 1) (4 3 2) (5 2 1) (5 3 1) (5 3 2) (5 4 1) (5 4 2) (5 4 3) (6 2 1) (6 3 1) (6 3 2) (6 4 1) (6 4 2) (6 4 3) (6 5 1) (6 5 2) (6 5 3) (6 5 4))
```

I understand that this is not a real "problem" since I've already managed to solve it (with some external help). I'm just curious about the reason behind this difference.

Comment: `map` simply _maps_ a function over each element in a list, returning a new list as a result. `flatmap` does the same, but additionally _flattens_ the list, that is: if the result was a list of lists, it combines all the sublists in a single list.

Comment: Additionally, if you could simply replace `flatmap` with `map` at every use site and get the same results, nobody would have bothered to invent `flatmap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` replaces each element of a list with a new element in its place:

```
   1        2        3        4               ...
  10       20       30       40               ...
```

`flatmap` replaces each element of a list with some new elements in its place:

```
   1        2        3        4               ...
  10 11    20                40 41 42 43      ...
```

As you can see, if some element is replaced with no elements at all by `flatmap`, it is the same as if it were *filtered out* from the input list.

And if you substitute `flatmap` with just `map`, then each element of a list will be replaced with a *list* of some new elements in its place:

```
   1        2        3        4               ...
 (10 11)  (20)      ()      (40 41 42 43)     ...
```

(edit:) and that's not what you want, here, because you want the empty lists to disappear, to achieve the filtering effect.

So what you were supposed to do here, is to *conditionally* produce them at the last step of expansion and splicing-in the new values, achieving the filtering *that way*, as

```
(define (unique-triplets-sum n s)
  (define (unique-triplets-summing-up-to s a) 
     (flatmap (lambda (i)
        (flatmap (lambda (j)
            (flatmap (lambda (k)              ;; NB: flatmap
                       (if (= (+ i j k) s)
                         (list (list i j k))  ;; NB: (list _triplet_)
                         '()))                ;;     OR _empty_list_
                (enumerate-interval 1 (- j 1))))
             (enumerate-interval 1 (- i 1))))
          (enumerate-interval 1 a)))
  (unique-triplets-summing-up-to s n))

>  (unique-triplets-sum 5 8)
'((4 3 1) (5 2 1))
```