# Explication of Scheme code for permutations

Tags: scheme, permutation, definition

Here is a Scheme code to produce the permutations of a list of elements:

```
 (define (remove x lst)   (cond
     ((null? lst) '())
     ((= x (car lst)) (remove x (cdr lst)))
     (else (cons (car lst) (remove x (cdr lst))))))

 (define (permute lst)   (cond
     ((= (length lst) 1) (list lst))
     (else (apply append
            (map (lambda (i) 
             (map (lambda (j) (cons i j))
                  (permute (remove i lst)))) lst)))))
```

I do understand each part of the code if we take the code apart, but what I can’t understand is how this all leads to generating the permutations?

Let’s say we take the list `‘(a b)`, how does it generate `‘(a b)` and `‘(b a)`?

We start by removing `a` from the list and `b` stays, but where is written that you now have to cons `a` to `b`? `b` is a single element, but in my interpretation of the code, `b` will also be removed and there is nothing left…

Comment: The first step towards understanding the code would be to format it for human consumption. Break it up into lines, indent those properly. You're not going to be able to read this rectangle of stuff and neither are we. There are several editors with perfectly sensible autoindent for scheme (vim, emacs, ...).

Comment: @dratenik it was only partly *their* fault, but mostly it was an [SO formatting fault](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44592c6f-27b1-4128-83db-5e5088d16a95/view-source). after small fixes what remains is a bit idiosyncratic, yes, but still quite readable a formatting.

Comment: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63677178/sicp-ex2-41-map-and-flatmap/63732689#63732689) for a relevant insight. `(apply append (map f xs))` == `(flatmap f xs)`.

Comment: there is a bug in the `remove` function. consider `(remove 2 '(1 2 3 2 1))`.

Comment: @WillNess I don't think permute will work correctly with non-unique elements anyway

Comment: @dratenik why wouldn't it? permutation is a purely positional, structural operation. there would be duplicates, yes, but so what.

Comment: @WillNess what is your fix for remove - remove only the first match? Or did you have something more ambitious in mind? If it's the former then that's no longer positional. It would produce the correct number of sequences, but I don't immediately see that it would generate all the reorders.

Comment: @dratenik OK, it does depend on the interpretation/definition of "set", never mind.

Comment: @WillNess Sorry but I don’t see the bug?

Comment: I assumed it mustn't remove an element more than once. it depends on the  interpretation of list as set though, so never mind that comment.

Comment: Oh alright. Can someone explain the code to me please? With the help of my example if possible (or an example with a list of 3 elements). Thank you in advance.

Comment: @alinsoar the OP already provides a definition, they don't ask how to implement this, in general. and it's on lists, while on e.g. arrays it can be radically different. so I don't understand your removal of those two tags.

Comment: @WillNess Almost everything in scheme is on lists and I have never seen that tag added.  I understand to add it when you speak about the implementation of lists, about how Conses work, but not when you only need to use lists.

Comment: @alinsoar this specific question is about a given definition of list permutations. I'm reinstating the tags, I feel they are highly relevant. .... OK I took out the list tag. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would read the main part like this (in the order indicated by numbers)

```
   (map (lambda (i)     ;(1) for each i in...
      (map (lambda (j)  ;(3) for each j in...
           (cons i j))  ;(6) append i to front (of this shorter permutation)
         (permute       ;(4) ...the list of all permutations...
           (remove i lst))))    ;(5) ...of the input list with i removed
    lst)                ;(2) ... the input list
```

Answer (score 1):

`(apply append (map f xs))` == [`(flatmap f xs)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63677178/sicp-ex2-41-map-and-flatmap/63732689#63732689).

Re-writing your code in an equational pattern-matching pseudocode,

```
remove x [x, ...ys] = remove x ys           ; skip this x, and go on removing
            ; ( consider skipping just this one occurrence instead:
            ;       = ys                                           )
remove x [y, ...ys] = [y, ...remove x ys]   ;   (or else x /= y, so keep this y)
remove x [] = []                            ; until the list is exhausted

permute [x] = [[x]]
permute xs  = 
    xs                                ; ( with (xs |> f) == (f xs) )
    |> flatmap (x =>                  ; for each x in xs, 
          permute (remove x xs)       ;   for each permutation p of xs w/o x,
          |> map (p => [x, ...p]) )   ;      prepend x to p and 
                                      ;   splice the results in place of x
```

Is this clearer?

No? So, let's see how `permute [a,b]` is calculated.

First, what is `permute [a]`?

```
  permute [a] = ...
( permute [x] = [[x]] )
          ... = [[a]]
```

(it doesn't matter how we call the first element of a single-element list, it's still its first and only element). Similarly,

```
  permute [b] = ...
( permute [x] = [[x]] )
          ... = [[b]]
```

OK, but how does it help us see what's the result of `permute [a,b]`? Let's work with it step by step:

```
permute [      a,          b       ] =
   ;; for each x in (xs==[a,b])
   ;;          a           b           ; <<- the value of x
   ;;      remove x from xs
   ;;         [b]         [a]          ; <<- xs with x removed
   ;;      prepend x to each permutation of the above
   ;;       [[  b]]     [[  a]]        ; <<- permutations
   ;;       [[a,b]]     [[b,a]]        ; <<- prefixed with x
   ;;      splice them in by `apply append`
        [    [a,b]   ,   [b,a]     ]
```

So then, `permute [b,c] == [[b,c],[c,b]]`, etc. And, armed with this knowledge,

```
permute [        a,                b,                 c          ] =
   ;; for each x in (xs==[a,b,c])
   ;;      remove x from xs
   ;;          [b,c]              [a,c]              [a,b]
   ;;      prepend x to each permutation of the above
   ;;    [[  b,c],[  c,b]]  [[  a,c],[  c,a]]  [[  a,b],[  b,a]]
   ;;    [[a,b,c],[a,c,b]]  [[b,a,c],[b,c,a]]  [[c,a,b],[c,b,a]]
   ;;      splice them in by `apply append`
        [ [a,b,c],[a,c,b],   [b,a,c],[b,c,a],   [c,a,b],[c,b,a]  ]
```

Is that clearer?

Comment: Sorry but I’m a total beginner in programming. All I want is an explanation to my question, so: how does it generate ‘(a b) and ‘(b a)?

We start by removing a from the list and b stays, but where is written that you now have to cons a to b? b is a single element, but in my interpretation of the code, b will also be removed and there is nothing left... Please just in words and not pseudocode, thank you.

Comment: "where is written that you now have to cons a to b?" in the `map` call, `(map (lambda (j) (cons i j))`.here `i` is `'a` and `j` is `'(b)`. the latter is so because of the first clause in `cond`, `((= (length lst) 1) (list lst))`. you need to understand `map`, and you need to understand recursion, to understand this code in your post. you did say you understand every piece of code separately. :)

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort. This is not clearer, but I guess the problem is me and I am also afraid that you will not be able to explain this exercise to me, as I asked for an explanation in simple words. Still thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: @JeckCoeler maybe start by asking smaller, more focused questions about specific pieces of code. do you understand what `map` is doing? Do you understand what `apply append` is doing? what specifically is unclear? for instance, do yo understand that `(remove 'a '(a b))` == `'(b)`, and why? That `(remove 'b '(a b))` == `'(a)`, and how? that `(permute '(b))` == `'((b))`? that `(map (lambda (j) (cons 'a j)) (list '(b))` == `(list (cons 'a '(b)))` == `'((a b))`?

Answer (score 1):

(*TL;DR:* the verbal explanation is at the very end of this answer.)

Let's try following the definitions with `let*`-rewrites. The definitions are

```
(define (remove x lst)   (cond
    ((null? lst) '())
    ((= x (car lst)) (remove x (cdr lst)))
    (else (cons (car lst) (remove x (cdr lst))))))

(define (permute lst)   (cond
    ((= (length lst) 1) (list lst))
    (else (apply append
           (map (lambda (i) 
            (map (lambda (j) (cons i j))
                 (permute (remove i lst)))) lst)))))
```

We try

```
(permute '(a b))
≡
(let* ((lst '(a b)))
  (apply append
     (map (lambda (i)
             (map (lambda (j) (cons i j))
                  (permute (remove i lst))))
          lst)))
≡
(let* ((lst '(a b))
       (r  (map (lambda (i)
                  (map (lambda (j) (cons i j))
                       (permute (remove i lst))))
                lst)))
  (apply append r))
≡
(let* ((lst '(a b))
       (i1 'a)
       (r1 (map (lambda (j) (cons i1 j))
                       (permute (remove i1 lst))))
       (i2 'b)
       (r2 (map (lambda (j) (cons i2 j))
                       (permute (remove i2 lst))))
       (r (list r1 r2)))
  (apply append r))
≡
(let* ((lst '(a b))
       (i1 'a)
       (t1 (permute (remove i1 lst)))
       (r1 (map (lambda (j) (cons i1 j)) t1))
       (i2 'b)
       (t2 (permute (remove i2 lst)))
       (r2 (map (lambda (j) (cons i2 j)) t2))
       (r (list r1 r2)))
  (apply append r))
≡
(let* ((i1 'a)
       (t1 (permute '(b)))
       (r1 (map (lambda (j) (cons i1 j)) t1))
       (i2 'b)
       (t2 (permute '(a)))
       (r2 (map (lambda (j) (cons i2 j)) t2))
       (r (list r1 r2)))
  (apply append r))
≡
(let* ((i1 'a)
       (t1 '( (b) ))
       (r1 (map (lambda (j) (cons i1 j)) t1))
       (i2 'b)
       (t2 '( (a) ))
       (r2 (map (lambda (j) (cons i2 j)) t2))
       (r (list r1 r2)))
  (apply append r))
```

and so we get

```
(let* ((r1 (map (lambda (j) (cons 'a j)) '( (b) )))
       (r2 (map (lambda (j) (cons 'b j)) '( (a) )))
       (r (list r1 r2)))
  (apply append r))
≡
(let* ((r1 (list (cons 'a '(b))))
       (r2 (list (cons 'b '(a))))
       (r (list r1 r2)))
  (apply append r))
≡
(let* ((r1 (list '(a b)))
       (r2 (list '(b a)))
       (r (list r1 r2)))
  (apply append r))
≡
(let* ((r1  '((a b)))
       (r2  '((b a)))
       (r (list r1 r2)))
  (apply append r))
≡
(apply append (list '((a b)) '((b a))))
≡
(      append       '((a b)) '((b a)) )
≡
'(                    (a b)    (b a)  )
```

Follow the same technique if you need to convince yourself in the validity of the intermediate results.

---

In hindsight, we could simplify it a bit more aggressively, like

```
(let* ((lst '(a b))
       (i1 'a)
       (r1 (map (lambda (j) (cons i1 j))
                       (permute (remove i1 lst))))
       (i2 'b)
       (r2 (map (lambda (j) (cons i2 j))
                       (permute (remove i2 lst))))
       (r (list r1 r2)))
  (apply append r))
≡
(let* ((lst '(a b))
       (i1 'a)
       (t1 (permute (remove i1 lst)))
       (r1 (map (lambda (j) (cons i1 j)) t1))
       (i2 'b)
       (t2 (permute (remove i2 lst)))
       (r2 (map (lambda (j) (cons i2 j)) t2)))
  (apply append (list r1 r2)))
≡
(let* ((t1 (permute '(b)))
       (r1 (map (lambda (j) (cons 'a j)) t1))
       (t2 (permute '(a)))
       (r2 (map (lambda (j) (cons 'b j)) t2)))
  (append r1 r2))
≡
(let* ((r1 (map (lambda (j) (cons 'a j)) '( (b) )))
       (r2 (map (lambda (j) (cons 'b j)) '( (a) )))
       )
  (append r1        ; one row for each elt            '( a
          r2        ;  of the input list,                b
          ))        ;  spliced in place by append        )
```

etc., in the end revealing the structure of the computation in the more visually apparent manner:

- for each element of the input list,

  - find all the permutations of the remainder,
  - prepend that element to each of them,
- and join together the results from thus processing each element in the input list, by appending all those results together.

(thus justifying my other, pseudocode-based [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63756088/849891) here).

Comment: there is a verbal explanation at the end of _this_ answer. don't hesitate to ask more questions if something is still unclear. :)